# Prevent double entries in array

Tags: php, arrays

to understand the question, look through this code first:

```
$thuser = $_SESSION['username']; //current user
$sql = "SELECT sender FROM dm WHERE receiver = '$thuser'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    $t = 1;

    while ($partner = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $ptr = 'Partner'.$t;
        $chatpartners[$ptr] = $partner[0];
        $t++;
    };
} 
echo json_encode($chatpartners);
```

Now, the sql query will select multiple senders such as "John", "Eric", "James", "James".

My question is, how I can prevent "James" from being inserted into the array twice.

The array should look something like this:

```
{ Partner1: "John", Partner2: "Eric", Partner3: "James" }
```

and *not* like this:

```
{ Partner1: "John", Partner2: "Eric", Partner3: "James", Partner4: "James" }
```

How can that be achieved?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you can use `distinct(sender)` in your query or use `group by sender` in your query.

Comment: are you ready for your db to be attacked and possibly deleted? you may get a rude awakening one day, maybe that will open your eyes to sql injection prevention methods.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know I should use prepared statements, this just serves to make easier.

Comment: what do you mean by "easier"? that to a potential hacker/middle man, does make it "easier" for them to compromise your database. Always use a prepared statement, even from what you may think may be a trusted user.

Comment: @Fred-ii- easier for you guys to read and understand because whether I use prepared statements or not is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: sure but have you ever thought of potential future people visiting the question? ;-)

Comment: Sure. The thing is, though, that there is no user input at all. It takes your username that was saved to the session when logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`DISTINCT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) on your sql query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT sender FROM dm WHERE receiver = '$thuser'";
```

---

Another option is to use [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) like this:

```
$chatpartners = ['Partner1' => "John", 'Partner2' => "Eric", 'Partner3' => "James", 'Partner4' => "James"];

$chatpartners = array_unique($chatpartners);

echo json_encode($chatpartners);
```

Outputs:

```
{"Partner1":"John","Partner2":"Eric","Partner3":"James"}
```

Comment: Okay it works well now. Using DISTINCT is certainly the best option here. Thanks.